# Difference between delay() vs withTimeout() coroutine in Testing

Tags: android, testing, kotlin-coroutines

I'm writing some test case with coroutine

```
class ArticleViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private var likeCount = 0

    fun getLikeCount() = likeCount

    fun addLikeCount() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            likeCount += 1
            likeCount
        }
    }
}

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
private fun MainCoroutineRule.runBlockingTest(block: suspend () -> Unit) =
    this.testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
        block()
    }

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MainCoroutineRule(
    val testDispatcher: TestCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
) : TestWatcher() {

    override fun starting(description: Description?) {
        super.starting(description)
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description?) {
        super.finished(description)
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        testDispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
    }
}

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class ArticleViewModelTest {
    @get:Rule
    var mainCoroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()

    @Test
    fun addLikeCount() = mainCoroutineRule.runBlockingTest {
        val articleViewModel = ArticleViewModel()
        articleViewModel.addLikeCount()
        Assert.assertEquals(1, articleViewModel.getLikeCount())
    }
}
```

addLikeCount() test case above is working fine until I try to change logic addLikeCount().

case 1:

```
fun addLikeCount() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            delay(2000)
            likeCount += 1
            likeCount
        }
    }
```

case 2:

```
fun addLikeCount() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            withTimeout(2000) {
                likeCount += 1
                likeCount
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to delay 2 second (example: call API), then continuing handle logic (likeCount += 1, ....).

In case 1, addLikeCount() test case is fail

In case 2, addLikeCount() test case is pass

I don't know why? what is difference between delay vs withTimeout?
If you understand my problem, please help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: The difference is `delay` suspends the Execution on other hand `withTimeout` just add a timeout to the execution once timeout is reached before execution completes it with throw a `CancelationException` . U should have a look at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47171302/unit-testing-a-kotlin-coroutine-with-delay) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57496946/why-unit-tests-with-coroutines-delay-fails).

Answer (score 0):

`withTimeout` advances time instantly but with launch you need to use `advanceUntilIdle` or `advanceTimeBy(2000)` to move time where you can prior, middle or after states of events.